# Are there cards that turn opponents' life loss into my life gain?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was wondering if there is a card that says something like "whenever opponent loses life, you gain life." It doesn't matter how much life gain, just need to know if a card like this exists.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. As [this query](https://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3AWhenever+o%3A%22loses+life%22&v=card&s=cname) reveals, there's the following card:

> [Exquisite Blood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bExquisite%20Blood%5d)
>   {4}{B}
>   Enchantment
>   Whenever an opponent loses life, you gain that much life.

It combos nicely with [Sanguine Bond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSanguine%20Bond%5d) and [a number of other cards](https://magiccards.info/query?q=o%3A%22Whenever+you+gain+life%22&v=card&s=cname).

Comment: @doppelgreener, I already provided a link to the card. I included the search query as an example of what the OP could have done so they (and other readers) can learn. And I feel it's best to keep things as general, at least until it's found to generate too many matches.

Comment: Yeah but... it's a search that mentions both phrases... why would you not? (We *could* just include every card that mentions "life" and leave it at that, but there's a reason we won't.)

Comment: It's too easy to filter out legit results even when one thinks one knows the proper templating. If anything, I'm tempted to make it wider to include taking damage. /// Also, one gets to learn or related cards that could be included

Comment: Ok, sure, whatever floats your boat then. I've added a quote around the card quote at least.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to undo that.

Comment: No problem. And on further thought a 7 result query seems like a good idea even if it's got more results than necessary. (An enterprising searcher might go "but what if I filter it down with `o:"gain life"` as well.... aha!")